# Keep element centered in scroll-able div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a timeline for some kind of calendar, on the daily view, there are a vertical scroll and a red line that indicates the current time. Please take this jsbin as an example https://jsbin.com/pazufivige/edit?html,output

```html
<div style="width: 500px; overflow: scroll">
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 100px; background-color:grey;position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 2px; background-color: #EF5350; z-index: 5; left: 8%";></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to keep the red line in the centre of the div, so I want the scrollable div to scroll to the correct position so that it stays in the middle. The red line gets updated every minute and is on top of the planning, so I'll have to calculate the scroll position each minute. How would I go about this? I've googled a lot but couldn't really find something similar to my issue, can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: This will center the line `<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color:grey;position: relative;">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 2px ;margin:0 auto; background-color:#EF5350; z-index: 5;">
    </div>
  </div>`

Comment: I don't want to center the line, I want the scrollbar to move to the position where the line stays in the middle. @ArvindDhakad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the position of your 'red line' and scroll the window such that the position of the red line from the left of the window is half of your window width.

Simple steps to be followed:
 1. Find the relative position of the line form the left of the window.
 2. Find the width of the window.
 3. Use the scrollLeft method to scroll in such a way that the width on left side of the red line is same as width on the right side of the red line.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
width = $("#myWindow").width();
linePosition = $("#redLine").position().left;
console.log(linePosition);
let scroll= linePosition - (width/2);
console.log(scroll)
$("#myWindow").scrollLeft(scroll);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myWindow" style="width: 500px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <div style="width: 5000px; height: 100px; background-color:grey;position: relative;">
        <div id="redLine" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 2px; background-color: #EF5350; z-index: 5; left: 45%";></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot!